# Best way to share one keyboard and mouse between a Mac & PC?

Tags: mac, windows, software-recommendation

I have a Mac and pc sitting beside each other. Each has an independent monitor. Currently I am using a two port usb switch to move between the two systems, but it can sometimes be cumbersome to switch between the two quickly. Anyone have any other suggestions for ways to switch between the two systems?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about Apple hardware, software, or services as defined in the [Help Center](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: @Allan couldn't software be a solution to the issue though?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  This question is outside the scope of what can be asked here because it's not about Apple products per se.  It would be a better fit with [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).  That said, what you are using is fine...if you want to go wireless - look at [Logitech's MK850 line](https://amzn.to/2FvX1bv) that will pair with 3 devices simultaneously.  The [MX Master 2S](https://amzn.to/2w56erI) mouse allows you to move between two computers (PC and/or Mac) seamlessly; I have it and love it.

Comment: There's no software (without hardware) that will allow you to connect to a mouse/keyboard already connected somewhere else.   The question to ask is, how does software installed on one computer "see" hardware installed on another computer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never used it, but you can give [Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy) a try. It shares keyboard and mouse on one system with one or more systems using software. It works on macOS, Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 3):

After @Ömer Rıfat Kuldaşlı posted Synergy I also found something called [ShareMouse](http://www.keyboard-and-mouse-sharing.com). Not sure which is the best so far.

Answer (score 1):

Sharemouse has considerable lag, I can't recommend it.  I've been using  J5 Create JUC400 Wormhole Switch for years.  About 90% of the time it is great.  The other 10% it will make you tear your hair out.  Having just upgraded to a new Mac I may take this opportunity test Synergy.  But if you don't mind the occasional problems, the J5 unit is pretty awesome.  Joe Bob says check it out.

Comment: I can confirm your assessment of Sharemouse. It does not work reliably for me. The devs also are not very responsive. Also too expensive $129 IMHO. I am looking for a hardware solution.

Comment: I can also confirm this. I purchase Sharemouse and the support is awful. The devs are rude and expect another $129/year to continue to get updates. The software is way over-priced when free tools like Barrier work even better.

Answer (score 0):

I have an old Belkin OmniView KVM switch which I used to use to share one keyboard, monitor and mouse between a few machines. Unfortunately, it was only for the older VGA connectors, not the newer DVI/DP/HDMI type. However, I found later after I moved to DVI that it did support swapping the USB connector for the keyboard and mouse despite there being no VGA connections.

I would imagine that if you're fine with the two separate monitors and thus the video connector doesn't matter, you could find an older KVM on craigslist/ebay fairly cheap and just use the keyboard/mouse switching.

The only problem you'll run into is that the numeric keypad, Command, Alt Menu and Windows keys don't quite map the same between the platforms (e.g. the Command key becomes the Windows key which can be annoying to muscle memory of copy/paste functions). But a keyboard remapping can solve most of this.